# String.GetHashCode()は文字列が一致しなければ必ずユニークでしょうか？

Tags: c#, unity3d

ユニティで各アセットを管理するのにハッシュ値を適用しようと考えています。

ファイル名まで含んだフルパスに対してString.GetHashCode()からハッシュ値を
得ようとしております。

下記、MSDNを見る限り文字列が異なれば必ずハッシュ値が異なるように見えるのですが、
必ずユニークになるとの記述はないため、このまま使用していいものかわからずにいます。

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.80).aspx

知見をお持ちの方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Unityなので.Net2.0まで使用可能です。
Unityバージョンは5.0.1f1

【追記】
やりたいこととしては下記スクールストライクガールズのＰＤＦの74ページ目にある仕組みを作ることです。
http://www.jp.square-enix.com/info/images/image_technical_seminar2014_06/pdf/SQEX_DevCon_sugimoto.pdf

ファイルの実体を１つのバイナリデータとして保存し、
下記構造体のリストでファイルパスとオフセット位置とファイルサイズを管理するという
ファイルシステムを構築するためにファイルパスを可逆なものにしたいと思っています。

```
public struct FileSystemStruct
{
    public int HashCode;            // アセット名のハッシュコード
    public long OffsetPosition;     // ファイルシステム上のアセットデータの開始位置
    public long Filesize;           // ファイルシステム上のアセットデータのサイズ
}
```

【使い方】
ＵＩから指定パスのアセットをロードしたいというイベントが発生した時に、
指定パスをハッシュ化して、構造体のリスト内を検索してヒットした位置の
バイナリをロードするといった仕組みを構築するつもりです。

Comment: ここにある様に、MD5等でハッシュ文字列を生成すべきです。
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6839784/720391

Comment: MD5の場合、１つのファイルパスにつき文字列で32バイト必要なのでできれば数値型を用いて容量を削りたいです。

Comment: 念のため、「出力値が絶対に衝突しない（ユニークな）、汎用のハッシュ関数」という物は存在しませんよ。

Comment: 質問に追記しました。　
全くハッシュ値の生成を理解しておらず助かります、可逆で一意なキーを得る方法を調査してみます。
ファイルパスの部分が可逆で一意であれば検索可能だと思うのです。

Comment: 可逆と言っておられる意味が分かりません。可逆とは元のソースを圧縮し、その圧縮物**のみ**から元のソースが取り出せる事を言います。ハッシュは、ある情報群を取り出す際のキーに使われます。FileSystemStruct を key-value として格納するか、データベースに格納する事になるのかなと思いますが、そのキーこそが一意になるべき値なので、元の文字列と可逆になる必要はありませんね。キーはRDBMSに生成して貰えばいいのですから。kvs の様に自分でハッシュ文字列を生成する必要があるのならば、一意になるべき条件をすべて文字列化して特異な文字列をセパレータとして結合し、ハッシュ文字列を生成するのが一般的です。例えば `md5(FilePath+"|"+FileSize)`

Comment: 通常、ハッシュ関数は[一方向性関数](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E6%96%B9%E5%90%91%E6%80%A7%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0)の一種です。出力値`Out=Hash(In)`から入力値`In`を復元することは不可能、つまり原理的には非可逆な変換です。また、リンク先資料を見る限り、パス名→ID値にオンデマンド変換しているのではなく、”予め全てのリソースに連番IDを振った”と言っていませんか？

Comment: md5(FilePath+"|"+FileSize) このやり方とても素晴らしいです。
これであれば一意なキーが作り出せます。
Dictionary型にするのか、Forループで回せるような仕組みにするのかは
まだ決めてないのですが一意なキーの作り方は、このようなルールを決めたいと思います。

Comment: ＞”予め全てのリソースに連番IDを振った”と言っていませんか？
　確かに連番IDを振ったと書いてありますね、あらかじめアセットとIDとが対になっていると思います。　IDか配列のINDEXをUI側からもらえるような仕組みにすればうまくいくのではと考えています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

いいえ。異なる文字列から同じハッシュコード値を返すことが、メソッド仕様上ありえます。

`String.GetHashCode`メソッドのような「ハッシュ関数」は、一般に以下のような性質をもちます。

- 同じ入力データに対しては、必ず同じハッシュコード値を返す。
- 異なる入力データに対しては、**できる限り異なる**ハッシュコード値を返すよう設計される。
- 異なる入力データに対して、**偶然に**同じハッシュコード値を返すことはあり得る。（衝突）
- 2つの入力データの差異が小さくても、出力されるハッシュコード値は**なるべく分散**するように設計される。
- 得られたハッシュコード値から、元の入力データを**復元することはできない**。（一方向）

また`String.GetHashCode`メソッド固有の問題として、「動作環境が異なる場合、同じ入力データに対して、同じハッシュコード値を算出する保証がない」と明記されています。このメソッド（のデフォルト動作）は、プログラム動作中でのみ利用するハッシュ値専用であり、ファイルシステムのような永続化されるデータ管理に用いるべきではありません。

---

> ＵＩから指定パスのアセットをロードしたいというイベントが発生した時に、
>   指定パスをハッシュ化して、構造体のリスト内を検索してヒットした位置の
>   バイナリをロードするといった仕組みを構築するつもりです。

目指しているものは、[ハッシュテーブル](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB)実装のように聞こえます。この場合でも、ハッシュ値の**衝突**は必ず考慮しなければなりません。

色々と汎用性を考慮して独自実装を進めると、オリジナルファイルシステムの劣化版が出来上がる恐れもあります。どこかで前提条件を割り切るなど、制約を設けることを検討された方が良いと思います。

Comment: 異なる文字列からも同じハッシュ値が作られる可能性があり、動作環境が異なる場合は保証されないとなると、この方法を用いることは危険だなので止めようと思います。IDを使ってどのように管理するかはまだ思いついてないですがアセット毎に固有のIDを振って変換テーブル作るなり堅牢な作りに変えようと思います、

Answer (score 6):

`int`型である`GetHashCode()`は2^32通りの値しかありません。
これ以上の件数(例えば5文字の文字列の全組み合わせ)のハッシュ値をすべて計算すれば必ず衝突が発生します。

Comment: ファイルパスの数が２の３２乗を下回っていれば生成したハッシュはユニークであることが保証されるということでしょうか？

Comment: @user3732298 されません。最新のMSDNを確認してみて下さい https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: ＞ただし、各一意の文字列値に対して一意のハッシュ コード値は存在しません。 異なる文字列が同じハッシュ コードを返す場合があります。　　　と書いてありますね。バイト数が少なくて一意な値を取得できる方法を詳細に調査してみます。

Comment: @user3732298 どういうプログラムなのか分かりませんが、一意性を求めるより同一ハッシュに対して複数件の値を持たせられるような構造にした方が良いと思いますよ。

Comment: 質問に追記しました。
　　
ファイルパスが一意であればＵＩ担当者がどこから指定ファイルをロードしたいと思っても、必ず望んだファイルが手に入ると思っているのですが、そもそもハッシュ値に対する私の理解が足りないような気がしてます。

Answer (score 2):

スクールストライクガールズのＰＤＦの74ページ目の仕組みはアセット名からハッシュ値を作るよりもアセット名に順にIDを振っていき、アセット名を利用する部分をIDで置換していく方が的確な気がします。
リソースを統合し、ID情報からランダムアクセス可能にするというのがまず最初の目的になるでしょう。

"UIから指定パスのアセットをロードしたいというイベントが発生した時に、指定パスをハッシュ化する"までやってしまうなら、Dictionaryを利用してアセット名をidに変換する方がシンプルかつ見通しも良いと思います。

第２段階として、変換を0にしてDictionary型を排除することができるか検討する形になると思います。つまり、アセット名のハードコーディングの削除を目指します。

Comment: 確かにあえてハッシュ化するより、keyとなるIDを作った方が安全ですね。
そして無駄な変換や後々のアセットの追加や更新・削除に柔軟に対応する方法を模索してみます。

Answer (score 1):

他の方が言われているとおり、int型は、2^32通りのパターンしか表現できないので、衝突が発生します。

短い文字列であっても、衝突の可能性は、あり得ます。
MD5など他のハッシュアルゴリズムを使用した場合にも完全に回避できません。

衝突を回避する方法として、**GetHashCode**と併用して、**Equals**による判定を行います。
例えば、Dictionaryの内部実装は、GetHashCodeで簡易的な判定を行ったあと、
Equalsメソッドを呼び出し、オブジェクトの内容が一致するか判定を行っています。

Dictionaryのような型を使用した場合、ハッシュと併用として内容の一致判定まで行うので、衝突について気にする必要は、ありません。